# how to use jar from maven built locally

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

I pulled two projects from github to my laptop. lets call them A and B.

A is the project I'm working on and B has some utility classes I'm using in A.
(I added a dependency to A's pom file for the module I need in B).

I ran maven clean install on project B so that I can use the changes in A but when I do maven re-import on A I don't see them.

I'm pretty sure it is supposed to work. anyone know what I'm missing?
maybe some configurations on IntelliJ

Comment: have you also rerun `mvn deploy` on project A after the changes ?

Comment: no i've never used deploy actually with maven. I'll try...

Comment: I'm getting an unauthorized error.
which is o.k. I guess cause now I see that the deploy tried to right to remote repository which is not what I want because it is not my project. I want to work only locally for now until I will finish my feature and then push through CI system...

Comment: mvn install should be enough to share the libraries locally. What version do your dependencies have? If it's not a -SNAPSHOT version the artifact resolution will treat the dependency quite different that with fixed versions. And what happens when you do a "maven re-import"? What do you do there?

Comment: it was actually a version with -SNAPSHOT.
when I run clean install I don't see the jar in the .m2
I see an empty folder with the name of the version...

Comment: o.k. so I tried again and I saw a resolver-status.properties file and inside it said:
maven-metadata-XXX.repository.xml.error=Could not transfer metadata XXXX\:2.9.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to XXX.repository (http\://maven.XXX.com\:8081/nexus/content/groups/XXX-public/)\: Not authorized , ReasonPhrase\:Unauthorized.

Comment: @TalJoffe are you sure you are using the correct password?

Comment: you mean for the repository? yes checked the setting.xml and the password is correct. (I used it to manually login to the repository).
regardless I think it shouldn't be the issue because I'm trying to install and not deploy - I want to work with the local repository..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mvn clean install` is enough. After this command .jar will be copied do your `homeFolder/.m2` and may be used by other projects

Comment: I looked and the jar is not updated in the .m2 folder....
any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to run `mvn -U clean install`.
The `-U` flag will force a check for missing releases and updated snapshots.

Edit: after your comments, I am wondering if you are using the correct password, please try to verify this. Also, if you are not using any form of authentication try to remove this from your settings.xml file:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>SomeRepo</id>
      <username>SomeUN</username>
      <password>SomePW</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Comment: מצטער טל אני לא יודע מה הפתרון אז :(

Comment: thanks for trying it was probably something very sketchy. I reinstalled maven and now its o.k.

Answer (score 0):

so... after trying all of the answers and comments and some other stuff, I re-installed maven and now it works.

what I found is that instead of writing to .m2 it was writing to project directory so I suspect there was something wrong with the maven configuration files but I'm not sure what.

thanks and sorry for this weird issue